# Why do I need to qualify references to an object inside my companion object with "Companion." from outside the class

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

I have a `companion object` with a named `object` inside of it, but unless I use `Companion.` kotlin can't resolve the reference

```
class Cls {
    companion object {
        object Obj {
            val attr = 1
        }
    }
}


fun main() {
   println(Cls.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
   println(Cls.Companion.Obj.attr) // ok
   println(Cls.Obj) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
   println(Cls.Companion.Obj) // ok
}
```

If I switch to `val Obj = object { ... }` then neither access works if I try to reference `attr`, but both allow me to reference `Obj`

```
class Cls {
    companion object {
        val Obj = object {
            val attr = 1
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
   println(Cls.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
   println(Cls.Companion.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
   println(Cls.Obj) // ok
   println(Cls.Companion.Obj) // ok
}
```

I don't understand this behavior. What's going on? My only guesses would be around static initialization ordering problems.

Comment: I don't know the formal reasoning for it, but I assume it's because `Obj` is really a *type* nested *within* `Companion`, so you need the full path for that classifier type. So you need to explicitly use `Cls.Companion.Obj` to refer to it - whereas when referring to `Cls.Companion` itself (the object) you're allowed to omit `Companion` as a convenience. And when `Obj` is a property of that object (rather than a nested type declaration) you can access it like any other value. Some info here: https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#nested-and-inner-classifiers

Answer (score 0):

## First, Answering the second question.

> ```
> class Cls {
>     companion object {
>         val Obj = object {
>             val attr = 1
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> fun main() {
>    println(Cls.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
>    println(Cls.Companion.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
>    println(Cls.Obj) // ok
>    println(Cls.Companion.Obj) // ok
> }
> ```

Here the `object{}` is called as anonymous object which is assigned to the variable as `val object` It does not have any references.
[image]

When you check here,  `Cls.Obj` is of type `Any`.
So you cannot access like Any.attr because Any is root of all Kotlin class, it will only have default fucntions like `hashcode()`, `equals()`...

Since it is an anonymous object, you cannot do type cast.So no way to access attr directly.

To access attr , you can acheive with interface.

```
interface Foo{
    fun attrs():Int
}

class Cls {
    companion object {
        val Obj = object : Foo{
            var attr = 1
            override fun attrs(): Int = attr
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(Cls.Obj.attrs()) // Print attr value 1
}
```

Here is the compiled code looks like of this.

> ```
> public final class Cls public constructor() {
>     public companion object {
>         public final val Obj: kotlin.Any /* compiled code */
>     }
> }
> ```

When you see here, Obj is a variable inside which is of type Any.
In Kotlin, you can access variables inside companion object in both ways with or without Companion. Both will work.

```
  println(Cls.Obj) // ok
  println(Cls.Companion.Obj) // ok
```

In java , we need to access like,
`Cls.Companion.getObj()`.

In Kotlin ,Companion word can be ignored. So accessing variables in companion object is the better one without using companion,like below.

```
  println(Cls.Obj) // ok
```

## Coming to First Question

> ```
> class Cls {
>     companion object {
>         object Obj {
>             val attr = 1
>         }
>     }
> }
>
>
> fun main() {
>    println(Cls.Obj.attr) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
>    println(Cls.Companion.Obj.attr) // ok
>    println(Cls.Obj) // Error: "Unresolved reference: Obj"
>    println(Cls.Companion.Obj) // ok
> }
> ```

Here you use object inside companion object, which is a nested object. This is similar to Nested static class in java, but not the same.

> ```
> public final class Cls public constructor() {
>     public companion object {
>         public object Obj {
>             public final val attr: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

The above one is the compiled code of the first one. When you check here, you have object inside companion object. But in your second question, you have made that `Obj` as variable. So you can directly call that variable. But here since it is a nested object, you should use companion keyword to access `Obj`.

`Cls.Companion.Obj` **is the valid one.**

When you access Obj like this `Cls.Obj`,  the compiler checks for variable named 'Obj' inside that companion object. But there is no such variable because its an nested object.

And to make it clear,here is another example.

```
class Cls {
    companion object {
        object Obj {
            val attr = 1
        }
        object Obj1{
            val attr = 2
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.